# How to Estimate the Error Term in a Heteroscedastic Model with Regression Through the Origin

Tags: regression, variance, heteroscedasticity, intercept, blue

Suppose we have a NO INTERCEPT model, $$y_i=\beta x_i+e_i$$

where $e_{i}$ follows a N(0,$\sigma^2 x_i^h$), so $e_i$ is equal in distribution to $e_{0i} x_i^{\frac{h}{2}}$, where $e_{0i}$ follows a N(0,$\sigma^2$) .

I know that in order to obtain the BLUE (Best Linear Unbiased Estimator) of the $\beta$ coefficient, set $w_i = x_i^{-\frac{h}{2}}$.

$h$ can be estimated by calculating the marginal variances at each level of x.  Then, using the model $\log(\hat{e}_i^2)=\log(\sigma^2)+h\log(X)$ which yields $\hat{h}$, so $w_i = x_i^{-\frac{\hat{h}}{2}}$ .

This then gives the model $$y_i w_i = \beta x_i w_i + e_{0i}$$ which gives $\hat{\beta }=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i^2 x_i y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i^2 x_i^2}$.

I am looking to find $Var(\hat{\beta })=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i^2 x_i^2 }{(\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i^2 x_i^2)^2}Var(w_i y_i)=\sigma^2 \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i^2 x_i^2 }{(\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i^2 x_i^2)^2}$, but I'm not completely sure how to correctly estimate $\sigma^2$.

I am estimating $\sigma^2$ using the usual $s^2$ formula with the transformed data, $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(w_i y_i -\hat{\beta}w_i x_i)^2$.  Is this correct?  Should I be dividing by n-2 because I've estimated TWO parameters ($\beta$ and $h$)?

Comment: Rather than trying to fix up this *ad hoc* two-step approach (which will be complicated and perhaps not be worth the effort, since its statistical properties are unknown), why not select a suitable estimation procedure for $(\beta,h)$--Maximum Likelihood might work well--and apply it directly?

Comment: I suppose I'm using the two step approach because I would like unbiased estimates for the variance.  Not sure how to adjust the MLE estimator for the variance to correct it.

Comment: My sample size is not very large, so bias is not trivial.  Am I being too perfectionist?  Should I just an ML solution, as Zachary suggests below?

Answer (score 2):

First off I assume you mean $e_i \sim N(0,\sigma^2|x_i|^h)$ or that $x_i$ is always positive.  Otherwise you will get negative and or complex valued variances.

In practice, when we know heteroskedasticity exists but are unaware of its form we may use the two-step method of [Feasible generalized least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_least_squares#Feasible_generalized_least_squares) (FGLS).  However FGLS may be inconsistent.  So to @whuber 's point, given you know something about the heteroskedasticity structure, you can construct a *consistent*  maximum likelihood estimator (MLE) for your parameters.  The likelihood function would have the form 
$$
L=\prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sigma |x_i|^{h/2}}\phi \bigg(\frac{y_i-x_i'\beta}{\sigma |x_i|^{h/2}}\bigg) 
$$
Where $\phi$ is the standard normal pdf.
Your optimal parameter estimates may then be found by maximizing the log likelihood i.e
$$
(\hat \beta,\hat \sigma, \hat h)=\arg \max_{\beta,\sigma,h}\bigg\{\sum_{i=1}^{n}-\ln(\sigma |x_i|^{h/2})+\ln\bigg(\phi \bigg(\frac{y_i-x_i'\beta}{\sigma |x_i|^{h/2}}\bigg)\bigg) \bigg\}
$$ 
Which simplifies too
$$
(\hat \beta,\hat \sigma, \hat h)=\arg \max_{\beta,\sigma,h}\bigg\{-\frac{n}{2}\ln(2\pi)-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln\bigg(\sigma |x_i|^{h/2}\bigg)+\frac{(y_i-x_i'\beta)^2}{\sigma^2|x_i|^h}\bigg\}
$$

This is extremely useful as you can construct a hypothesis test for homoskedasticity.
$$
H_0: h=0
$$ 
$$
H_a: h\neq 0
$$
Where the null is homoskedasticity.

$Var(\hat \beta)$ may be estimated using the [fisher information equality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information), the negative inverse of the hessian of the above log likelihood evaluated at $(\hat \beta, \hat \sigma,  \hat h)$.  These estimates may be obtained using built in optimization and maximum likelihood routines for R, Matlab, Python, etc.  Below is an R example.

```
n=1e3
x=rnorm(n)
y=2*x+rnorm(n,sd=.1)
a.x=abs(x)
b.ols=solve(x%*%x)%*%t(x)%*%y
e=y-x%*%b.ols
var.ols=sum(e^2)/(n-1)
negative.log.like=function(pars)
{
    b=pars[1]
    h=pars[2]
    sig.sqr=pars[3]^2
    e=(y-x*b)
    s=sqrt(sig.sqr)*a.x^(h/2)
    e.adj=e/s

    OUT=(-sum(log(1/s)+dnorm(e.adj,log=TRUE)))
    #print(c(OUT))
    return(OUT)
}
init=c(b.ols,0,var.ols)
result=optim(init,negative.log.like,hessian=TRUE)
# estimates 
 result$par
    #standard errors
     sqrt(diag(solve(result$hessian)))
# maximum log likelihood
 -result$value
```